# How to output a clickable delete button using laravel collectives in yajra datatables laravel 5.7

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables, laravel-5.7, yajra-datatable

I wanted to output a clickable delete button on another column of the yajra datatable using the laravel collectives. The problem is that it outputs a raw html text `{!! Form::open(["action" => ["UsersController@destroy",28], "method" => "POST", "class" => "pull-right"]) !!} {{ Form::hidden("_method", "DELETE") }} {{ Form::submit("Delete", ["class" => "btn btn-danger"]) }} {!! Form::close()!!}")` in the view instead of a clickable delete button. I can output regular html tags but I want to use the laravel collectives. I am confused why it isn't working even if I already added `rawColumns()` function.

Here is my controller:

```
public function yajraDT()
{
    $users = User::all();
    return Datatables::of($users)
    ->addColumn('delete', function ($users) {
            return '{!! Form::open(["action" => ["UsersController@destroy",'.$users->id.'], "method" => "POST", "class" => "pull-right"]) !!}
            {{ Form::hidden("_method", "DELETE") }}
            {{ Form::submit("Delete", ["class" => "btn btn-danger"]) }}
            {!! Form::close()!!}")';
    })
    ->rawColumns(['delete'])
    ->make(true);
}
```

Here is my view:

```
<script>
     $(function() {
           $('#tableDT').DataTable({
           processing: true,
           serverSide: true,
           ajax: '{{ url('users/yajraDT') }}',
           columns: [
                    { data: 'id', name: 'id', 
                        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->type == "Admin")
                            render:function(data, type, row)
                            {
                                return "<a href='/users/"+ row.id +"'>" + row.id + "</a>"
                            }
                        @endif},
                    { data: 'first_name', name: 'first_name' },
                    { data: 'last_name', name: 'last_name' },
                    { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
                    { data: 'gender', name: 'gender' },
                    {data: 'delete', name: 'delete'}
                 ]
        });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I do it:

```
// in the controller

return Datatables::of($users)
    ->addColumn('delete', function ( $user ) {
        return view('user.delete', compact('user'))->render();
    })
    ->escapeColumns([])
    ->make();
```

Then your `delete.blade.php`

```
{!! Form::open(["action" => ["UsersController@destroy", $user->id], "method" => "POST", "class" => "pull-right"]) !!}
    {{ Form::hidden("_method", "DELETE") }}
    {{ Form::submit("Delete", ["class" => "btn btn-danger"]) }}
{!! Form::close()!!}
```

This way you don't have hard-coded HTML in your controller, and you can render the html output before displaying.

Another suggestion is to move your Admin check from the JS code into your controller, you can use the `editColumn` method on the Datatable.

Comment: But that means it will have to redirect to another page right? Is there a way for it to not redirect to another page? I wanted it to not redirect to another page.

Comment: This delete button is another column in the datatables, not in a new page too.

Comment: it will not redirect, it will render the html that needs to be output in each of your datatable rows. Just try it out.

Comment: Okay thank you I'll try it out as soon as I get home.

Comment: I tried it out but It outputted the raw html text, not the clickable delete button.

Comment: do you still use `->make(true);` or just `->make();`?

Comment: I tried both with and without true still the same. If it helps, this is what I put

`$users = User::all();
            return Datatables::of($users)
            ->addColumn('delete', function ( $user ) {
                return view('users.delete', compact('user'))->render();
            })->make(true);`

Comment: @Karl please check my edit above, and use that one. I noticed an issue on github for the Datatables, and this was a suggested addition which worked for couple of users. So try it out.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't notice the edit. It's working now thanks! May I please know why it wasn't working before?

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't notice the edit. It's working now thanks! May I please know why it wasn't working before?

Comment: it might be an issue in the `rawColumns` method of the library in version 7.0 of the datatables, you can check the issue [here](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/949). 
Please accept my answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I think laravel collective is for blade so no need to put it on controller. Simply :-

```
public function yajraDT()
{
    $users = User::all();
    return Datatables::of($users)
    ->addColumn('delete', function (User $users) {
            return '<a href="admin/user/'.$users->id.'></a>';
    })
    ->rawColumns(['delete'])
    ->make(true);
}

//ROUTE Start
Route::get('admin/user/delete/{id},'Users@destroy');
//ROUTE End

//Remove User
public function destroy($id){
 try{
      User::where('id',$id)->delete();
      return back()->with([
      'message'  => 'User removed successfully."
     ]);
    }catch(Exception $e){
       return back()->with([
          'message' => $e->getMesssage() 
       ]);
    }
  }
```